# How do I get over this forward declaration error?

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

I'm trying to do a barebones example of a class A that provides callback methods to a dependent class B by passing a reference to itself.  The best I've produced is the following:

## a.h

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

#include "b.h"

namespace b {
    class ClassB;
}

namespace a {

    class ClassA {
    public:
        ClassA();
        b::ClassB* m_b;
        void callback(const std::string& msg);
    };
}

#endif
```

## a.cc

```
#include "a.h"

a::ClassA::ClassA() {
    m_b = new b::ClassB(this);
}

void a::ClassA::callback(const std::string& msg) {
    std::cout << msg << '\n';
}

int main(void)
{
    a::ClassA* doit = new a::ClassA();
    delete doit;
    return 0;
}
```

## b.h

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace a {
    class ClassA;
}

namespace b {
    class ClassB{
    public:
        ClassB(a::ClassA* a_inst);
    };
}

#endif
```

## b.cc

```
#include "b.h"

namespace b {

    ClassB::ClassB(a::ClassA* a_inst) {
        a_inst->callback("Call me maybe");
    }
}
```

This is the closest I can get to a compilation, but I'm left with the following errors:

```
b.cc: In constructor 'b::ClassB::ClassB(a::ClassA*)':
b.cc:6:9: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct a::ClassA'
b.h:8:8: error: forward declaration of 'struct a::ClassA'
```

How can I fix this?  And is there a better way to construct this relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your file `b.cc`, you must include `a.h`.

 In the .h file you can't because of multiple inclusion but since `.cc` files are not included, they can include whatever they want.

**Note :**

You should not forward declare b in your `a.h` file because it is declared in `b.h` and you included it.

You could also, as stated @chris, remove the `#include "b.h"` in your `a.h` and put it in your `a.cc`.

Comment: You should go the other way on the last part. You don't need more than a forward declaration, so don't include the file. a.cc is what needs to include it.

Comment: It's the opposite of what you state in your answer. You're preferring to include files over use forward declarations.

Comment: You suggest removing inclusions from header files, forward declare instead and include onmy from source file ?

Comment: Yes, you should prefer forward declarations when possible. You immediately gain the benefit of not having to recompile that file when the one with the forward-declared class changes. In some cases, it's necessary to resolve cyclic dependencies.

Comment: I get your point. When I'm in the OP's situation, I use to do one forward declaration and one inclusion. I am going to edit my answer.